# Why am I getting to routed to the boot menu?

Tags: boot

I had been messing around in disk manager trying to set up a bootable Windows 10 drive for someone else. I closed the disk manager, and a day or so later my laptop died and restarted. Now it will not load Ubuntu; it just brings me to the boot menu, and when I select Ubuntu it just sends me back to the boot menu. I was able to boot from a USB. I'm worried I messed something up from disk manager. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

The Ubuntu version is 18.04.3 and I have a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Answer (score 1):

Haha okay so I had deleted the EFI system partition (ESP), which is just fantastic. I decided to use TestDisk to recover my files (booting from USB) and then did a clean install of Ubuntu. If anyone knows if there is a relatively straightforward way of restoring a deleted ESP, I would love to know, just out of curiosity! I tried restoring the deleted partition with TestDisk, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a new question about the EFI partition

Comment: Just do a total reinstall of grub & it will recreate the files. If partition UUID/GUID changed the recovery of files may not work as UEFI uses GUID to know which FAT32 partition has .efi boot files. You can restore files, but may have to use efibootmgr to create new correct UEFI boot entry and/or edit /EFI/grub.cfg to configfile with correct UUID for grub.cfg in full install.